# Shell - Redirected namepiped tmp log file of nohup out writing junk logs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, named-pipes, file-processing

I am trying to create a logrotate script for a running nohup output ( without any line breakages - tried `logrotate` package in system and observed several log lines are getting missed while rotating the continuously generating log file). Here's the steps i followed,

- Run the below script in background

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> log_split_pipe="/tmp/log_split_pipe"
> log_rename_interval_in_sec=60
> log_file="/home/application/Logs/appname.log"
> semaphore="/home/application/Logs/appname.log.pause"
> write_log()
> {
>  while read line
>  do
>   while [ -f $semaphore ]
>   do
>    sleep 1
>   done
>  echo "$line" >> $log_file
>  done < $log_split_pipe
> }
>
> write_log &
> log_start_time=$(date +%s)
> while true
> do
>  tim_diff=$(expr $(date +%s) - $log_start_time)
>  if [ $tim_diff -ge $log_rename_interval_in_sec ];then
>   touch $semaphore
>   mv /home/application/Logs/appname.log /home/application/Logs/appname-$(date +%Y'_'%m'_'%d'_'%H'_'%M).log
>   rm -rf $semaphore
>   log_start_time=$(date +%s)
>  fi
> done
> ```

- mkfifo /tmp/log_split_pipe
- run application as

> nohup ./application 2>&1 1 >/tmp/log_split_pipe &

Here the problem is, to the log file `/home/application/Logs/appname.log` I am getting junk texts instead of the proper logs written by the process.

Can anyone help on the problem with the logic and to rectify?

Comment: "Junk"? Could you elaborate? "instead of" - so none of the expected output? Is it possible your app is receiving that spaced-apart `1` as a behavior-changing relevant argument instead of part of the output redirection? Have you checked for other processes writing to the same location?

Comment: Yes, what i meant is the proper application output log is not writing to the log file if i follow the above step. If i directly give the nohup out to a regular file the logs are fine. and also, i have cross checked the same case with other java based processes too, where the issue is same. So now, not sure if the issue may occur for all the `stdout` logs from any process which continuously write  to a name-piped file. As i mentioned above, I was trying to create a log rotate script without any line miss for high log generating files.

Comment: @PaulHodges : can my explanation help you to find me a right solution, pls?